# Connect to online database using node.mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js

Is it possible to connect to my online database using node.mysql. I'm using cPanel as my hosting site. So far I've tried this approach

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'www.agrilif3.com',
  user: 'secret',
  password: 'secret',
  database: 'SmartSurface'
});
```

But this code gives me this error `ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'secret'@'202.92.128.112' (using password: YES)` 
After this I've tried replacing the host to `202.92.128.112` and now this error shows up

```
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
    at Connection._handleConnectTimeout
```

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong and any tutorial site on how to achieve this will be usefull thanks

Comment: Are you sure you're able to access the server? Have you tried logging from the command line with these credentials?

Comment: I use the username and password of cPanel to the user and password.

Comment: I think you need mysql username and password for that. Not cPanel credentials.

Comment: soo how can i get my mysql uname and pass? I tried adding user to my database and replacing the node.mysql credential with that but still no luck

Comment: You need to read `cPanel` documentation for that. I think you're doing it fine the `nodejs` way but you need to ensure you're using right credentials. Try those credentials from terminal in order to ensure they're right : `mysql -usecret -psecret  -hwww.agrilif3.com`

Comment: seems like I can't connect using any of my known credentials.. I'll go read the cPanel documentations for now. thank you